# Running Eclipse Luna using Oracle Java 8 on Mavericks

Tags: macos, java, eclipse

I am trying to run [Eclipse Luna](http://eclipse.org/downloads/) using Oracle Java JRE 1.8.0_11 on Mac OS X 10.9.4. I have added the following line to my [`eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file:

```
-vm 
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

Eclipse seems to have picked this up, but now I get the following message when starting it:

```
The JVM shared library "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/
JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/server/libjvm.dylib"
does not contain the JNI_CreateJavaVM symbol.
```

I have made sure that both Eclipse and Java are 64 bit versions, and do not know what else could cause this problem. Can anyone propose a fix for this?

*Edit:* It seems to work when using the JDK instead of just the JRE, but I still would like to know why.

Comment: Oracle's use of JRE is confusing what you have is the plugin for a browser and not the full old JRE so for Eclipse you need the JDK - actually the JRE might be enough but it is in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Comment: Actually, when just installing the JRE, the directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` remains empty. The strange thing is that apparently all the required files are there, but for some reason it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

JRE is Java Runtime Environment which is used for running java applications. But if you want to develop Java applications and do Java programming, you need JDK i.e. Java Development Kit.

To know more see the following question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre

Comment: You can run eclipse from the ire but to develop java with eclipse you need the JDK

Comment: I know that, I do not plan on using Eclipse for developing Java, I just need to run it.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Eclipse will not run without JDK on any platform either it's a Mac, PC or Linux. To run Eclipse, you MUST have JDK installed in your system.

Comment: @PratikaRana note the definition of JRE in the link you give is not what Oracle now says the OSX JRE download is - and to run Eclipse a prier JRE will work - but OSx's is not so we need the JDK to run

Comment: @Mark, would you care to write a full answer with that information, so I can give you some points for it? This question seems to attract quite a few views, so that might be helpful.

Comment: Just to correct the above statements, which are false. Eclipse in general does not require a JDK to run *or* to develop Java, it is generally sufficient to use a JRE to use Eclipse (although it is recommended to have a JDK since it includes the source for the standard Java libraries). However, in the latest versions of OS X, it does not install a JRE in a usable way, so the workaround is to install the full JDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. Uninstalling Eclipse and the JRE, and then installing the JDK and re-installing Eclipse worked for me.